# apache2 build fails in yocto - "/usr/local/include" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]

Tags: apache, build, autotools, yocto, openembedded

I was trying to build `apache2` on yocto.
But I was getting below errors.

> ERROR: This autoconf log indicates errors, it looked at host include and/or library paths while determining system capabilities.
>   Rerun configure task after fixing this.

Some googling led me to 
https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2012-March/005125.html

So I looked into `conf.log` and find out those lines:

```
cc1: warning: include location "/usr/local/include" is unsafe for
cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: warning: library search path "/usr/local/lib" 
is unsafe for cross-compilation
```

I googled again but, I couldn't understand 3 things yet:

1. Why has the PATH been set to local path ?
2. Why does this error only come when building `apache2` [ I can build `ngnix`, `cryptsetup`, etc..]
3. How can I fix it?

Comment: But it is not an error is a warning. What branch Yocto is using? You put on pastebin the entire log of the apache2 build and link here.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these types of errors come from configure scripts that have paths (like `/usr/local/include`, `/usr/include` and all sorts of other variations) hardcoded into them. So the way to fix it is to patch `configure.ac` (if there is one in the package, of course, `configure` otherwise) removing this paths.

For example, take a look at [patch for pure-ftpd](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/7e4f22517ada29f634970721481f0a7de1f3bffd/meta-networking/recipes-daemons/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd/0001-Remove-hardcoded-usr-local-includes-from-configure.a.patch) from current meta-oe, it solves similar problem:

```
--- a/configure.ac
+++ b/configure.ac
@@ -100,18 +100,6 @@ AC_ARG_VAR(PYTHON,local path to the python interpreter)
 python_possible_path="/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/opt/python/bin:/opt/python/usr/bin:/opt/python/usr/local/bin"
 AC_PATH_PROG(PYTHON,python,/usr/bin/env python,$python_possible_path)

-if test -d /usr/local/include; then
-  CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I/usr/local/include"
-fi
-
-if test -d /usr/kerberos/include; then
-  CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I/usr/kerberos/include"
-fi
-
-if test -d /usr/local/lib; then
-  LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/usr/local/lib"
-fi
-
 CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2"

 dnl Checks for header files
```