# Getting warning "include location '/usr/local/include' is unsafe for cross-compilation" every time I try to compile using `clang -Weverything`

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors, clang, cross-compiling

Apologies if this question isn't clear, I'm struggling to even start debugging this issue. I'm on macOS and I'm now getting the following error / warning every time I compile C programs  using `clang` with `-Weverything and -Werror` flags:

`error: include location '/usr/local/include' is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Werror,-Wpoison-system-directories]`

Initially I thought this was an issue related to my code, but I discovered that this error now occurs with every program I try to compile. I've never had this error before despite always compiling with those flags, and because it now occurs with every program, I suspect it's something that's changed with my compiler or my system. The only thing I can think of that has changed recently was me making a few shared folders with a Lubuntu VM on VirtualBox and updating Xcode.

I can compile the program without the `-Weverything` flag and it appears to work as expected, but I'd like to address the actual issue to continue using `-Weverything`. As others have mentioned as well as this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181789/how-to-use-clang-with-std-c11-weverything-werror/14185534#14185534), using `-Weverything -Werror` is excessive in real-life scenarios, however, I'm primarily using it as a learning tool and I want to understand why this issue comes up even for basic programs like `helloworld.c` (see below).

I've come across a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799950/apache2-build-fails-in-yocto-usr-local-include-is-unsafe-for-cross-compilat), but the answer references a `configure.ac` file that I'm not familiar with and not sure how to use.

Let me know if I can provide any more information to help debug this issue.

As an example, here are the results from `cc -Weverything -Werror -v helloworld.c`:

```
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.15.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name helloworld.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=10.15.6 -fcompatibility-qualified-id-block-type-checking -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 609 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Weverything -Werror -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/Projects/helloworld -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 204 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.15.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/mn/v00y5wf55qjf76r4q9rvxq1c0000gn/T/helloworld-89fdc3.o -x c helloworld.c
clang -cc1 version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2) default target x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
error: include location '/usr/local/include' is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Werror,-Wpoison-system-directories]
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You've changed an environment variable, or some other compiler setting, that makes the compiler think that you are cross-compiling for the VM, instead of compiling for the host machine. You should compile a simple "hello world" program with the `-v` option, and then copy/paste the output into the question.

Comment: Show your full `clang` command line.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks, i've added the output from running `cc -v helloworld.c`

Comment: @EricPostpischil do you mean what i type when i compile my program? it is `cc -Weverything -Werror [ProgramName].c`

Comment: On my machine `/usr/local/include` is listed as a nonexistent directory. You could try renaming it temporarily, to see if that removes the error.

Comment: Clang 11.0.0 shows `/usr/local/include` in the search list (if it exists in the system) but does not produce a warning. So this may be new behavior in Clang 12?

Comment: `-Weverything -Werror` is in general pretty silly.  `-Weverything` warns about all sorts of constructs, many of them perfectly innocuous.  It includes basically every possible warning that the compiler developers thought that anybody might possibly want in any possible circumstance.  It's meant for testing the compiler and not for actual use.  And yet you are saying you want compilation to abort if any of those warnings happen to be triggered?

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/14185534/634919

Comment: In particular, `-Wpoison-system-directories` is specifically designed to *only* be useful when cross-compiling.  When compiling for native, it makes no sense to use it, and will *inevitably* produce warnings that mean nothing.  I don't really see any sensible answer to your question besides "don't do that"; don't request a warning that you don't want, and certainly don't make it an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use clang++ with -std=c++11 -Weverything -Werror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181789/how-to-use-clang-with-std-c11-weverything-werror)

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge, it's good to know that using `-Weverything` is overkill. I'm primarily using it as a learning tool. With that being said I'd still like to better understand why this warning came up suddenly where as it was never an issue before.

Comment: A temporary solution I've found so far is to just exclude `-Wpoison-system-directories` from compilation using `-Weverything -Wno-poison-system-directories -Werror` when compiling, although it still feels to be an incomplete fix. There's mention of a similar problem [here](https://github.com/AOMediaCodec/libavif/issues/284), which suggests that it's a macOS issue and was able to recreate the warning using `--sysroot /usr/include`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Apple tools are configured to provide and use all the necessary headers and libraries within Xcode.app, avoiding the host system’s headers and libraries. Essentially, the default compilation and link for Xcode **is** a cross-compilation; it targets a set of systems fully defined within Xcode.app, agnostic of the fact that the host system is one such system. So I am more surprised that Clang seems to include `/usr/local/include` by default than that it is set to poison system directories. At least, the default behavior ought to be either to include it or to poison it, not both.

Comment: @NateEldredge: As I noted, in my installation with Clang 11, the OP’s options, with `-Weverything`, include `/usr/local/include` but do not complain it is unsafe. So there may have been a change between 11 and 12.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options to get rid of this warning.

1. Ignore this warning with the `-Wno-poison-system-directories` option.

Note that prefixing with `-Wno-` works for all warnings.

Full command:

```
cc -Weverything -Wno-poison-system-directories -Werror helloworld.c
```

2. Set the logical system root with the `-isysroot` option.

Full command (if the developer command lines tools are installed):

```
cc -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -Weverything -Werror helloworld.c
```

Full command (using the SDK from inside Xcode):

```
cc -isysroot "$(xcode-select --print-path)/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" -Weverything -Werror helloworld.c
```